# Set custom marker image as center instead of bottom in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using `Leaflet` for my project, as pr `Leaflet` Documentation we can use Custom image for put marker on map. i set marker using [L.Icon](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) and its working fine, but marker is staring from Bottom Position. But i want to set my marker image center of that Latitude and Logitude.

Here is an explanation using Image

[image]

And I want Like this

[image]

here is My Code

```
 var icon = window.L.icon({
                    iconUrl: "MYICON_SVG_IMAGE",
                    iconSize: [50, 50],
                    iconAnchor: [25, 50],
                    popupAnchor: [0, -40],
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `iconAnchor: [25, 50],` (the bottom) to `iconAnchor: [25, 25],` (the center)

```
var icon = window.L.icon({
                    iconUrl: "MYICON_SVG_IMAGE",
                    iconSize: [50, 50],
                    iconAnchor: [25, 25],
```

Comment: Thanks but when i zoom and zoom out the map, i think its still stay on bottom position instead of center

Comment: i mean when i zoom and zoom out map, bottom of marker stay on current position instead of center part.

Comment: My answer is the obvious fix to the issue indicated in your question.  If there is an additional issue, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates it (preferable a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself).